The COM port is connected with pySerial but doesn't return data
I'm trying to use the pySerial library to access an FPV controller through the COM port. I have this code:
port = '/dev/cu.usbmodem0x80000001'
baudrate = 115200

import serial
import time

def read_vtxtable():
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate, timeout=5, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
        time.sleep(2)
    except serial.SerialException as e:
        print(f"Cant open this port {port}: {e}")
        return []

    # Trying to initialize process and make controller alive
    ser.write('status\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(0.05)

    # Asking controller about vtx data
    ser.write('vtxtable\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(0.05)

    response = ""
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 5:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            response += ser.read(ser.in_waiting).decode()
        time.sleep(0.05)

    ser.close()
    return response

vtxtable_data = read_vtxtable()

print(vtxtable_data)

When I try this code, the connection appears to be successful, but when I request some data, the response is empty.
Interestingly, after I run some commands in the BetaFlight CLI, and disconnect to release port access, my own code starts working. However, if I unplug the USB and plug it back in again, the code stops working again.
Could it be that the code fails to "wake up" the controller, such that it ignores the commands? It seems like the BetaFlight CLI is able to do this, if so.
How can I get a non-empty response from the connection?


UPDATED
Below I have given the main idea of ​​what I changed in the code
Code
....
cli_prompt = "Entering CLI Mode, type 'exit' to return, or 'help'"
timeout_time = time.time() + timeout
while time.time() < timeout_time:
    write('#')

    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        buffer += ser.read(ser.in_waiting).decode()
        if cli_prompt in buffer:
            print("# Found wakeup phrase:", cli_prompt)
            return True
        else:
            print("# No response..")

            write('status')
            time.sleep(0.1)

            output = get_info()
            if len(output) > 0:
                print("# The board is alive")
                override_wakeup_detection = True
                return True
            else:
                write('#')

    time.sleep(0.1)

Output.
% python3 get_data.py
# Using first usbmodem found: /dev/cu.usbmodem0x80000001
# No response..
# No response..
# No response..
# The board is alive
[
'vtxtable',
 'vtxtable bands 8',
 'vtxtable channels 8',
 'vtxtable ...
]


You're sure the baud rate is 115,200?

@TimRoberts Yes, the baud rate is 115200
Also, after executing the commands in the BetaFlight CLI, my code starts working.
I think, if the baud rate was not correct, I think the code would not work in any case

Well, it depends.  With a USB serial device, the baud rate on the USB end doesn't mean anything.  What I was wondering is if there was some extra (non-serial) configuration required to set the device's actual baud rate.  If the BetaFlight code knew how to do that, it might have left it at another setting.  Just a wild stab.  Do you know if the device has other USB interfaces?

@TimRoberts device has only one USB interface.

@TimRoberts about 115200 this is the default value for such controllers and is also the value specified in the BetaFlight  documentation  as well

The thing is you are NOT using a real serial port. You're using a device connected through USB that emulates a serial port through a driver. You should be able to send keystrokes to the port just by using echo in a terminal window, or even connecting a terminal to a serial port. That's what the original terminals did. Check this question . The fact that the CLI tools leave the port open suggests they do "something" to wake up that driver and get the device working.

As for 115200, it really doesn't mean anything. Yes, USB-serial manuals show this as the default but the actual physical devices may NOT use that speed. 115K is a lot when the actual communication is over two unshielded wires. And guess what - the actual hardware manuals are terrible.  I found that out the hard way a decade ago. Try inspecting the settings after using the BetaFlight CLI with stty to see what the actual settings are

BTW the chip that gave me trouble yeas ago was made by FTDI, just like the ones mentioned by Betaflight. The problem was that FTDI's driver didn't handle the CTS/RTS signals automatically. This required a driver fix. Serial's docs show that rtscts and dsrdtr aren't enabled by default. Try setting these to True

Please include shell conversation as text, not as a screenshot.

@TimRoberts As the source shows, the OP's code sets the serial parameter, explicitly the baudrate. I'd expect that former setups are overwritten by that.

@thebusybee It depends.  With a USB device, that baud rate setting gets converted into a USB request.  The device might or might not do anything with that number.  It depends on the hardware.  But yes, it could be a dead-end.

The problem is solved, so I want an idea for a solution.
The ports and baud rate were selected correctly. The problem, as I indicated, was in the wake-up method.
Solving the problem is re-requesting the status a few more times

Updated the description, added a solution
